# Syntax for excluding deprecated directories with Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, deprecated

I have a few directories in my Java project that hold deprecated code: com.company.deprecated and com.partner.company.deprecated. I want to exclude everything in these two "deprecated" directories from Maven compilation, regardless of content or directory structure inside them, so I have created a build tag like this at the very end of my POM:

```
    <!-- Exclude directories that hold deprecated code -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/com/company/deprecated</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/com/partner/company/deprecated</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This POM handles a module inside a larger project, but the deprecated code isn't used anywhere else inside other modules, so I don't think there are any conflict issues going on with other POMs. I have tried putting the "build" element at the end of either the specific module POM or the project POM, and get the same compilation errors each time.

As far as I can tell, this should exclude the deprecated directories from my Maven build, but I keep getting compilation errors in files within the "deprecated" directories. I have tried the double asterisk syntax above, absolute paths, and wildcards after "deprecated" but nothing seems to work. I've gone through StackOverflow and haven't found anything exactly like what I'm trying to do, although I am still relatively new to Maven so it is very possible there is something I'm just being dense about.

Can anyone please help me with the proper syntax (or perhaps a different plugin?) for this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Tried `**/deprecated/**` (it follows ["ant style path pattern"](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) ..but i have doubts regarding "overall scenario"... have you tried just to (reversably) delete them?

Comment: @xerx593 Adding the double asterisks at the end worked; thanks! Don't want to delete the deprecated code yet for various reasons but being able to exclude it from the build works just as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Remove them from your project... that's much simpler...